# Is a normal web app automatically a PWA if service worker is integrated?

Tags: service, web-applications, progressive-web-apps, service-worker, worker

if I integrate a Service Worker into a WebApp, is it considered a PWA?
I developt a WebApp and want to include a Service Worker. I dont know, if this is now a PWA.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are only 3 core technical requirements for making your web application work as a PWA.

- *manifest.json* file
- Service worker integration with fetch event handler
- Your web app should be served under *HTTPS*.

**Web Manifest.json:-** Manifest file contains meta data information related to your web application which will be used when you install your web app (as PWA are installable).

```
{
    "short_name": "A PWA app",
    "name": "a PWA app",
    "icons": [
        {
            "src": "/images/icons-192.png",
            "type": "image/png",
            "sizes": "192x192"
        }
    ],
    "start_url": "/"
}
```

**Service Worker:-** Service worker is needed to cache and serve your app resources (e.g. static files). However it provides many functionalities apart from caching e.g:-

- Push notification
- Offline user experience
- Browser API such as camera, location

**HTTPS Network:-** This is needed for security reasons as service worker can intercept all the request between the client and server.

References:-

https://web.dev/progressive-web-apps/

https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/primers/service-workers